# Any ideas for an algorithm to take some specific data from a Nx3 matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is : I have no idea how to proceed to achieve that pattern below. (Well, I tried many approachs, but without success)

---

I have a `matrix` Nx3 (RowxCol): `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`

Visually should be something like this:

```
|01, 02, 03| ----- > |M(00), M(01), M(02)|
|04, 05, 06| ----- > |M(10), M(11), M(12)|
|07, 08, 09| ----- > |M(10), M(21), M(22)|
```

---

And I need to retrieve some data following this pattern to get a `matrix` (2N)xN:
`[[02, 04, 07], [03, 04, 07], [01, 05, 07], [01, 06, 07], [01, 04, 08], [01, 04, 09]]`
Visually :

```
|02, 04, 07| ----- > Second, First,  First (of each row)
|03, 04, 07| ----- > Third,  First,  First
|01, 05, 07| ----- > First,  Second, First
|01, 06, 07| ----- > First,  Third,  First
|01, 04, 08| ----- > First,  First,  Second
|01, 04, 09| ----- > First,  First,  Third
```

The idea is to get the second and third value from each row and complete the rest of spaces in the row with the first value from each row. I said `Nx3` because `N` can be increased, but how I'm stucked with a 3x3 I used that for example.

Comment: I see no way to apply your pattern for N>3 if you insist on an output shape of 2Nx3. 2NxN seems possible and is an easy extension, but 2Nx3 only works if you give extra information on how each output row should be created since you have N input rows, demand that the first entry of each input row should be in the output row (or for one row the second/third entry) but restrict the size to 3. That does not work.

Comment: Oh, that's true. 2NxN is what should be returned. (I think that I messed up a little bit when was writing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is rather simple, if it is okay for you to loop once over `N`:

```
import numpy as np
N=4  # set some arbitrary value for the dimension
M=np.reshape(np.arange(N*3), (N,3))  # create a dummy matrix
out=np.zeros((2*N,N)) # output matrix with size 2N x N, all zeros
out[:,:]=M[:,0]  # fill each column of the matrix with the first entry of M's rows
for i in range(N): 
    out[2*i,i]=M[i,1] # fill in the second value of M at position (2i, i)
    out[2*i+1,i]=M[i,2] # fill in the third value of M at position (2i+1, i)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help =)